# Check if the div contents are scrolled to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if a particular div's content are scrolled to bottom using the browser's scrollbar(vertical) and issue an alert. I need to know if all contents are scrolled down for a div and add new contents into it.

Any suggestions on how to do it?.

EDIT: No overflow set, i need to know end of div contents by scrolling the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

There are some properties/methods you can use:

```
$().scrollTop()//how much has been scrolled
$().innerHeight()// inner height of the element
DOMElement.scrollHeight//height of the content of the element
```

so you can get it like this

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('#YourDivId').bind('scroll', function()
                              {
                                if($(this).scrollTop() + 
                                   $(this).innerHeight()
                                   >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                                {
                                  alert('end reached');
                                }
    })
  }
);
```

Comment: I get alert regardless of the position of my scroll bar, so this doesnot work for me

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function IsScrolledToBottom(divID) {
  returnVal = false;

  obj = document.getElementById(divID);

  if ( obj.scrollTop == (obj.scrollHeight - obj.offsetHeight) ) {
    returnVal = true;
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

All you need to do is call this function on the div element, which will return true if it has been scrolled to the bottom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ran the code in my console, i get the value of returnVal always true whatever be the position of the scroll bar.

Comment: Just made a code amendment, give that a try.  This is the same code I use so it should work.  If it doesn't, please give an example of the area your trying to use it again, with CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: still same, not working. .. the div style is:
border-left: 1px solid ;
margin: 0 0 0 192px;
padding-left: 18px;

Comment: Have you set the overflow? overflow-y: scroll?

Comment: I have not set overflow, i need to know end of div contents by scrolling the browser scroll bar. I hope i am explainable here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16407/discussion-between-kailash19-and-williamtroup)